# Find all Foo's containing a Bar with Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class `Foo` and a class `Bar` where `Foo` has a many-to-many relation with `Bar`.

`Foo` looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Foo", catalog = "xxx")
public class Foo implements java.io.Serializable{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Set<Bar> allBars;

    public Bar(){
        allBars = new HashSet<Bar>(0);
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Foo_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getId(){
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name = "Name", nullable = false)
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String n) {
        this.name = n;
    }

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable (name = "Foo_Bars", catalog = "xxx", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "Foo_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) },
            inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "Bar_id", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    public Set<Bar> getAllBars() {
        return this.allBars;
    }

    public void setAllBars(Set<Bar> allBars) {
        this.allBars = allBars;
    }
}
```

And `Bar` looks like this

```
@Entity
@Table (name = "Bar", catalog = "xxx")
public class Bar implements java.io.Serializable{
    private int    id;
    private String name;

    public Bar(){}

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "Bar_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Column(name="Name",  nullable = false)
    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String nm){
        this.name = nm;
    }
}
```

**Problem**

I want to have a method called `public List<Foo> retrieveFooForBarId(int bar_id)` in my `FooDaoImpl` class so I can retrieve all `Foo`'s that contain a certain `Bar`.

*Example*

I have 2 `Foo`'s, the first contains 2 `Bar`'s, the `Bar`'s with `id=1` and `id=2`. The second `Foo` contains also contains 2 `Bar`'s, one with `id=1` and one with `id=3`. Both `Foo`'s contain the `Bar` with `id=1`.

In `SQL` the query would be

```
SELECT * FROM Foo
LEFT JOIN Foo_Bars ON Foo.Foo_id = Foo_Bars.Foo_id
WHERE Foo_Bars.Bar_id = 1;
```

How do I achive this with Hibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need `Foo`, you can use HQL

```
from Foo foo
left join foo.allBars bar
where bar.id = 1
```

However, the generated SQL will be something like

```
SELECT Foo.* FROM Foo
LEFT JOIN Foo_Bars ON Foo.Foo_id = Foo_Bars.Foo_id
WHERE Foo_Bars.Bar_id = 1;
```

that means, `foo.allBars` will not be retrieved, and hence be fetched lazily.  This maybe slightly different from your requirement

Answer (score -1):

If you are using hql you can use equivelent query

you have

```
public List<Foo> getFoo(long id) {
       Session session =   HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
          List<Foo> feeds = null;
        try {
                Transaction tx=session.beginTransaction();
                feeds = (List<Foo>) session.createQuery(
                   "from Foo as foo " 
                   +"left join foo.bar as bar "
                  +"where bar.id=:id")
                  .setParameter("id", id)
                   .list();
           }Catch(HibernateException e){
             System.out.println("Exception "+e);
             if(tx!=null){
                   tx.rollback();
            }   
         }
```

Comment: And does this result in a `List<Foo>`?

Comment: It is not a valid HQL.  It should be something like `from Foo foo left join foo.allBars bar where bar.id=1`.

Comment: @AdrianShum and does that resiult in a `List<Foo>` or do I have to do something extra for that?

Comment: That should result in `List<Foo>`.  Just a side note that if you do a `left join fetch` instead, the result will be something out of your expectation.  Forget it if you are not going to do so :P

Comment: @AdrianShum could you put that in an answer?

Comment: Check it by executing the code.For clear result you must post your pojo

Comment: @xrcwrn after several edit, your HQL is still wrong... for parameters in HQL, it should be `:id`.  And, mentioning `getCurrentSession()` and `session.beginTransaction()` is not only unrelated, but also not necessary correct for OP.